# How to set new values to a class

Tags: javascript, class, object, prototype

I have a rectangle class and I want to use shift to assign new values to this.x and this.y by the shift amount. For example, the coordinates were assigned (5,5) r.shift(3,3) will make this.x and this.y (3,3). Currently, my code makes x and y new values, it doesn't reassign them. How would I go on to do so?

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, width, height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
}

Rectangle.prototype.shift = function (changeInX, changeInY) {
  this.x = changeInX
  this.y = changeInY
}
//returns value string
Rectangle.prototype.toString = function () {
  return 'x is ' + this.x + ', y is ' + this.y + ', width is ' + this.width + ', height is ' + this.height
}
//offsets coordinates by amount
Rectangle.prototype.offset = function (changeInX, changeInY) {
 return new Rectangle(this.x+changeInX, this.y+changeInY, this.width, this.height)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `this.x += changeInX`  noting the `+=` to increment `this.x`?

Comment: No, doing this.x += changeInX results in my x being zero.

Comment: After the `+=` change I mentioned, try:  `const rect = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4); rect.shift(100, 200);  console.log(rect.toString())`

Comment: Thank you, it worked the first time but the numbers I was using messed me up

Comment: No offence, but I'll vote to close as "caused by typo" then, seeing how this was just a bit of an honest face-palm mistake on your part, with little value to others.

Comment: When I said it worked the first time, I meant the code you suggested worked the first time. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `+=` instead of just `=` to increment `this.x` in your `shift` function.

e.g.:

```
  this.x += changeInX
  this.y += changeInY
```

Full modified example:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, width, height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
}

Rectangle.prototype.shift = function (changeInX, changeInY) {
  this.x += changeInX
  this.y += changeInY
}
//returns value string
Rectangle.prototype.toString = function () {
  return 'x is ' + this.x + ', y is ' + this.y + ', width is ' + this.width + ', height is ' + this.height
}
//offsets coordinates by amount
Rectangle.prototype.offset = function (changeInX, changeInY) {
 return new Rectangle(this.x+changeInX, this.y+changeInY, this.width, this.height)
}

const rect = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log('before:', rect.toString())
rect.shift(100, 200);
console.log('after:', rect.toString())
```